# Attachment isn't loaded from customer portal

Tags: customer-portal, attachment

I have URL link to download attachment. Downloading gives out a error from customer portal.
How to correct it?

```
<a href="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!a.id}" download="{!a.name}">{!a.name}</a><br/>
```

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: "The unknown error of the server is found. Repeat attempt or contact his administrator."
But If to attach the page to a site, the attachment is downloaded.